# How to check if json return value is in the form of an array or a dictionary

Tags: arrays, json, dictionary, swift4, json-deserialization

Im using swift 4 to process json returned from a URLSession call. the json is saved to a dictionary (cache of type ) after the call using the URL string as the key. I then want to process the json to a custom object called ApodJSON. Sometimes the json returned is an array of my ApodJSON object and other times its a single ApodJSON.

when i use swift's new JsonDecoder `images = try JSONDecoder().decode([ApodJSON].self, from: data)` I get an error message if the json previously code returned an *individual* object ie "Expected to decode Array but found a dictionary instead."

How can i check if the json data is an *array* of json data or an indiviual item in *dictionary* format to allow me to call the appropriate JSONDecoder method. The following check if data is Array doesn't work

```
    // parse json to ApodJSON class object if success true
func processJSON(success: Bool) {
    // get the data stored in cache dic and parse to json
    // data is of type Data
    guard let data = self.dataForURL(url: self.jsonURL), success == true else { return }
    do {
        var images: [ApodJSON] = []
        // check if data is an array of json image data or an indiviual item in dictionary format
        if data is Array<Any> {
            images = try JSONDecoder().decode([ApodJSON].self, from: data)
        } else {
            let image = try JSONDecoder().decode(ApodJSON.self, from: data)
            images.append(image)
        }
        for image in images {
            print("ImageUrls: \(String(describing: image.url))")
        }
    } catch let jsonError {
        print(jsonError)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func processJSON(success: Bool) {
     // get the data stored in cache dic and parse to json
     // data is of type Data
     guard let data = self.dataForURL(url: self.jsonURL), success == true else { return }
     var images: [ApodJSON] = []
     do {
       // try to decode it as an array first
         images = try JSONDecoder().decode([ApodJSON].self, from: data)
         for image in images {
            print("ImageUrls: \(String(describing: image.url))")
         }
     } catch let jsonError {
        print(jsonError)
        //since it didn't work try to decode it as a single object
        do{
           let image = try JSONDecoder().decode(ApodJSON.self, from: data)
           images.append(image)
        } catch let jsonError{
           print(jsonError)
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: yes that worked thx. not sure if there are other ways to check upfront but this achieved what i was trying to do